# Referencing app/web.config-configured WCF services from code

Tags: c#, wcf

Suppose my *web.config* contains the following service definition:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Services.Redirector">
        <endpoint address="/_api"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="AutoHostedPickerTestWeb.Services.IRedirector"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Is there a way to reference the service host (or even endpoint) from my code? Something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ServiceHost host = WCFStaticMagic.GetHostByName("Services.Redirector");
     //....
}
```

I want this for **debugging purposes** - I realize this is probably bad practice for production code. I'm trying to create an HTTP redirection and I want to make sure that the absolute address of the endpoint is what I think it is (as you can see I give it a relative address). I can't create the service in code to begin with due to permission issues.